# Intermittent behavior in my AJAX, Greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey

I've a small Greasemonkey script that doesn't include any random part, but its results change with each page reload.

I'm a noob and I'm probably doing something wrong, but I don't know what. I hope you'll be able to help me.

The code is too large and too poorly written to be reproduced here, so I'll try to sum up my situation:

- I have a list of links which have `href=javascript:void(0)` and `onclick=f(link_id)`.
- `f(x)` makes an XML HTTP request to the server, and returns the link address.
- My script is meant to precompute `f(x)` and change the href value when the page loads.

I have a function `wait()` that waits for the page to load, then a function `findLinks()` that gets the nodes that are to be changed (with xpath).
Then a function `sendRequest()` that sends the xhr to the server. And, finally `handleRequest()` that asynchronously (`r.onreadystatechange`) retrieves the response, and sets the nodes previously found.

Do you see anything wrong with this idea?

Using a network analyzer, I can see that the request is always sent fine, and the response also.

Sometimes the href value is changed, but sometimes for some links it isn't and remains `javascript:void(0)`.

I really don't see why it works only half the time...

```
function getUrlParameterFromString(urlString, name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(urlString);
    if (results == null) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return results[1];
    }
}

function getUrlParameter(name) {
    return getUrlParameterFromString(window.location.href, name);
}

function wait() {

    var findPattern = "//a";
    var resultLinks = document.evaluate(findPattern, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

    if (resultLinks == null || resultLinks.snapshotLength == 0) {
        return setTimeout(_wait, 100);

    } else {
        for (var i = 0, len = resultLinks.snapshotLength; i < len; i++) {
            var node = resultLinks.snapshotItem(i);
            var s = node.getAttribute('onclick');
            var linkId = s.substring(2, s.length - 1); // f(x)->x
            sendRequest(linkId, node);
        }
    }
}

function sendRequest(linkId, nodeToModify) {

    window.XMLHttpRequest ? r = new XMLHttpRequest : window.ActiveXObject && (r = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));

    if (r) {
        r.open("POST", "some_url", !0);
        r.onreadystatechange = function () {
            handleRequest(nodeToModify, linkId, r);
        }
        r.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        r.send(linkId);
    }

}

function handleRequest(nodeToModify, num, r) {
 if (r.readyState == 4) {
     if (r.status == 200) {
         console.log('handleRequest() used');
         var a = r.responseText;
         if (a == null || a.length < 10) {
             sendRequest(num, nodeToModify);
         } else {
             var url = unescape((getUrlParameterFromString(a, "url")).replace(/\+/g, " "));
             nodeToModify.setAttribute('href', url);
             nodeToModify.setAttribute('onclick', "");
         }
     } else {
         alert("An error occurred: " + r.statusText)
     }
 }
```

}

```
wait();
```

Comment: It could be anything from a race condition, to page-load delays, to needing closures around the AJAX functions.   Chip the code down to a small example that exhibits the error and post that here.  Failing that, post the entire, unedited script.

Comment: how exactly are you waiting for the page to load?, I bet there is the mistake because it make no sense that sometimes it work and sometimes it don't (scripts are like math, 2+2=4 all the time, if it worked, it should always work)

Comment: Okay, [there](http://pastebin.com/LDGHhAkw) is the entire script. I tried to simplify it to make it more readable, I hope I didn't make a mistake while purifying it. In any case, it works (sometimes only, hence my question). Sorry if it's not really readable, it wasn't meant to be used by anyone but me.

Comment: ogps92, sorry I was posting while you commented. The way I'm waiting for the page to load is that I stay in the same loop while I can't see the links. Refer to the code above for details. But the problem shouldn't be there, since I **always** am able to send the correct requests (as many requests as there are links), and I always receive the correct answer from the server (as seen from a network sniffer). It's just that sometimes for an unknown reason the href value isn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that script will change exactly 1 link.  Look-up "[closures](http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies)"; **this loop:**

```
for (var i = 0, len = resultLinks.snapshotLength; i < len; i++) {
    var node = resultLinks.snapshotItem(i);
    var s = node.getAttribute('onclick');
    var linkId = s.substring(2, s.length - 1); // f(x)->x
    sendRequest(linkId, node);
}
```

**needs a closure** so that `sendRequest()` gets the correct values.  Otherwise, only the last link will be modified.

**Try:**

```
for (var i = 0, len = resultLinks.snapshotLength; i < len; i++) {
    var node = resultLinks.snapshotItem(i);
    var s = node.getAttribute('onclick');
    var linkId = s.substring(2, s.length - 1); // f(x)->x

    //-- Create a closure so that sendRequest gets the correct values.
    ( function (linkId, node) {
            sendRequest (linkId, node);
        }
    )(linkId, node);
}
```

Comment: You're right, it appears that only the last link is modified. It's hard to check since in my test sample there are only two links. But I would swear I've seen the two links correctly modified in some occasions, though I have made so many changes to the code that I can't be sure anymore. I am sure I have never used your syntax though, since I didn't know what closures are. The sad news is that I've tried the modification you described, but it is still only the last link that gets its href value modified.

Comment: Are you sure the closure code was used as shown? Link to the full script and a target page.  There may be an additional problem in that `wait()` may be firing too soon -- before all the relevant links are loaded -- especially if the page is AJAXing-in links.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I copy pasted it. The linkId of sendRequest(linkId, node) was working fine even without your code modification. I could see (with a sniffer) that two different linkIds were requested to the server. Is it the 'node' part that poses problem ? Isn't there a function toString() or something to display the value of a node in a console so that I know which node I'm dealing with, and whether there's a bug that causes me to always use the same 'node', hence the reason why only one would get modified ?

Comment: You can use `console.log();`, For example: `console.log('node = ', node);`  Also the code is sometimes using a variable `num` that is not properly defined.

Comment: Where can I access this console in firefox ? It's not ctrl shift J is it ? Yeah sorry about 'num', as I said I tried to refactor the code to simplify it. I forgot that one. It's just linkId, not num. It's right in my version though.

Comment: Best thing to do is install the excellent Firebug add-on.  Then the console opens with `F12` or `Ctrl` `F12` (or appropriate mouse clicks).

Comment: That's what I was using to see the net traffic, I just didn't notice there was a console :/. So, I put a console.log() at the first line of each function (except for handleRequest, because it is called even when the request hasn't finished downloading; see original question edit for details), and I noticed that... sendRequest is correctly called as many times as there are links on the page, but handleRequest is only called once... How can that be ?